# Getting previous events when subscribing to pub/sub events

Tags: javascript, eventsource

I'm building a web application where a user can queue a job for processing.  The back end log might contain:

```
10:57: Job 101: Part 8 of 10 completed
10:58: Job 101: Part 9 of 10 completed
10:59: Job 100: Part 4 of 7 completed
11:00: New Job Queued.  ID will be 102
11:01: Job 100: Part 5 of 7 completed
11:02: Job 101: All 10 parts completed
11:03: Job 102: started
11:04: Job 100: Part 6 of 7 completed
11:05: Job 102: Part 1 of 12 completed
```

The front end code looks like this:

```
axios.post('/job').then((res)=>{
  var job_id = res.body // job_id will be 102
  var source = new EventSource("/status?job_id="+job_id);
  source.onmessage = (event)=>{
    updatePageWith(event.data)
  }
})
```

Because the EventSource subscribe isn't instant, it's possible that the first message sent back from the server will be "Part 2 of 12 completed", missing the update for Part 1.  Is there any way to ensure that no events are missed, short of also providing a method to get all the events for a given job?

Comment: _"it's possible that the first message sent back from the server will be "Part 2 of 12 completed", missing the update for Part 1. Is there any way to ensure that no events are missed"_ That would be a server side issue, not an issue with `EventSource`, yes?

Comment: Yes.  I'm looking for a way to guard against the lost update.  I've "solved" the problem with the posted solution below, but I'm sure I'm not the only person with this issue.

Comment: Not sure how `message` event does not receive first event stream from `php`? Are you using `$_SERVER["HTTP_LAST_EVENT_ID"]` at `php`?

Comment: Not using php at all.  With the code in my question, the job is created on line 1 and starts processing on the back end right away, potentially before line three is run and the EventSource is created.

Comment: Can you store the results of the task until `EventSource` is created, then at first response to `EventSource` serve the event stream containing the stored values, delete the store values after first event stream response and continue with the stream?

Comment: In my domain this solution won't work, because there are multiple clients which need to subscribe to updates.  Perhaps I'm using the wrong tool for the job here though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving with the following:

```
var tracking_id = require('uuid/v4')()
var source = new EventSource("/status?tracking_id="+tracking_id)
source.onmessage = (event)=>{
  updatePageWith(event.data)
}
axios.post('/job', { track_with: tracking_id }).then((res)=>{
  var job_id = res.body // job_id will be 102
})
```

I realize there's a small chance that the job starts processing before the EventSource is registered and receiving updates, but the chance is reduced because the EventSource object doesn't wait until the job is created on the server to initialize.